# No minimal imperfect graph of order 200

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Prove that there is no minimal imperfect graph of order 200, without using the Strong Perfect Graph Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well-known that for a p-critical graph $|G|=\alpha(G)\omega(G)+1$
(where $\alpha$ is the independence number and $\omega$ the clique number)
and that they have both $\alpha(G)$ and $\omega(G)$ at least 2.
Since 199 is prime this is a contradiction.
Do you need proofs of any of the statements (they are not very hard)?

Comment: Shame on me... It was so simple! Just forgot this classical Lovasz result... Thank you!